# Trouble creating time delay in verilog

Tags: verilog, delay

I am trying to use a time delay in my code in Verilog. In the file I am making I have an always block, inside it a case statement, and the multiple parts of the case values should contain the delay. 
I tried testing it a simple program with LEDs. I wrote the delay in a single line, but it doesn't seem to be working!! No delay happens. What is going on here??? 
The line is :
for(i=0;i<=100000000;i=i+1) @(posedge clock);
And also, how can I add the delay in a random place?

Here is my code, it's a simple one just meant to test the delay:

```
module testni (clk, keypad, led1, led2);
input [0:6] keypad;
input clk;
output reg led1=1;
output reg led2=1;
integer i;
always@(keypad) begin
led1=0;
for(i=0;i<=100000000;i=i+1) @(posedge clk);
led2=0;
end
endmodule
```

I am trying to do this: do one statement, then wait 2s then do another statement. Shouldn't this wait 2s and then turn the led2 off??? But in my case they are both off the whole time.

Comment: please show your code.

Comment: And please explain more what you mean by "time delay" Do you mean clock cycles?

Comment: I updated and added the code. I mean that I need the program to pause and not follow through with the code for 2s.

Comment: you need to take a tutorial in verilog. It is not a generic programming language. You cannot use sequential programming style there.  Besides it seems like you want it to be synthesizable into fpga. The sample you have is not synthesizable.

Comment: Can you show me how to do it instead :/ I really need my program to wait, to hold on for 2 seconds and not change anything.

Comment: what is frequency of your clock?

Comment: it is 50 MHz...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most FPGA synthesis tools want you to describe hardware as a state machine. That means each clock cycle, [`@(posedge clk)`], look at the current state and other inputs, then determine the next state and outputs. Something like this

```
module testni (
  input clk,
  input [0:6] keypad,
  output reg led1,
  output reg led2
);
reg [31:0] counter;
integer state;
parameter IDLE = 0, COUNTING = 1;


always@(posedge clk) begin
            case(state)
          IDLE: begin 
                   led1 <= 1; led2 <= 1; 
                   counter = 0 ;
                   if (keypad) STATE <= COUNTING;
                end
          COUNTING: begin
                   led1 <= 0;
                   counter <= counter + 1;
                   if (counter > 100000000) begin
                          led2 = 0;
                          STATE <= IDLE;
                        end
          default: STATE <= IDLE;
        endcase
endmodule
```

Notice there is only one `@(posedge clk)` at the beginning of the always block.